# Cant run any JS related thing. MVC page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
@model TripGMap.Models.PhotoModel.Photo

    <div>
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">

            <a id="single_1" href="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3712/9032543579_1217e6566b_b.jpg" title="Singapore from the air (Andrew Tan 2011)">
                <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3712/9032543579_1217e6566b_m.jpg" alt="" />
            </a>
        </dl>
    </div>

@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#single_1").fancybox({
                helpers: {
                    title: {
                        type: 'float'
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

This is my View. I cant run any js here. As you can see i am trying to run a fancybox on my image but it's not working. It's just sending me to the image source ;/. What am i doing wrong?

I already tried to delete @section scripts thing and so on. Still JS doesnt work. I even added some  connections on the View.

Any suggestions? What's wrong? What am i missing?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Is your js code even outputted in HTML source?
- Look at the console, is there an error? If so it should tell you what's wrong.
- You included jQuery before or after your code? If after, your code will not work since jQuery is not even initialized when you try to access it via `$`.